# Artisan command affecting wrong database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two laravel apps, the first is used as a Server Management System (SMS) that creates a host on the server. When this host is created it does a git clone to bring in the second laravel app that is used as a CMS for that host.

What I am trying to do is create a plugin within the SMS so that you can just select a check box and it will install the CMS for you when you create a new host. I have most of the code in place and I am testing locally and everything works grand until at the end when I try to install the migrations, when I try to run;

```
'php artisan cms:update'.
```

I also tried;

```
'php artisan migrate'.
```

What ends up happening is that rather the command being run against the CMS database, it is affecting the SMS's database adding a couple of tables and breaking the SMS database. I have done a 'pwd' and checked to make sure I am in the correct directory;

```
'/Directory/Directory/host/cms'
```

As it makes more sense for someone to read all of the code rather than snippets here is a link to the plugin:

[CODE LINK](https://github.com/RobinJ1995/penguinControl/blob/town-cms-installer/resources/plugins/towncms-installer/TownCMSManager.php)

So to clarify what I need is to be able to test the plugin locally so I need the migrations to install into the correct database, and make sure the CMS works before I push to production. If anyone could shed some light on why the migrations is affecting the SMS rather than the CMS it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look into [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/envoy) to help automate some of these tasks. It is built for just this purpose (Not to be confused with Envoyer which is a paid, hosted version application of Envoy)

Comment: Go in with `php artisan tinker` and do `config('database')` to see what settings it's picking up. My guess is you've copied the `.env` file over.

Comment: @jfadich I will have a look at Envoy cheers man.

Comment: @ceejayoz that sounds like a possibility, I will investigate this when I get back into the office tomorrow. Good man.